# VBA- Need help to do average rows if data present in the other columns

Tags: vba, excel-formula, average

I have a excel sheet which we may keep adding rows/ deleting them.

And I have an average value present in some cell.I would want the excel formula to identify if there is text in another column to average the columns

So now if I insert another row, I have to manually update the average formula.

Is there a way to have a formula which check if column A is not empty, it should consider the data in column G for the average

Comment: You can select all the rows and columns you want even if blank and use a sum formula divided by a count formula `COUNTA` so as and when new columns rows get added they are already included in the formula. Keep the range broad enough to the max you possibly expect to be entered

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of approaches to this. My current favourite is a `CELL:INDEX(...)` expression. For instance, to find the last populated cell in the first continuously populated range between B1 and B5000, I would use (probably as a named range)  `$B$1:INDEX($B$1:$B$500,MATCH(TRUE, $B$1:$B$500="", 0)-1)`.

This approach is great because it's non volatile, so it shouldn't bog your worksheet down. It might be vulnerable to `$B$500` gradually shrinking if you're only ever deleting rows, though. Alternatives are referencing the whole column (`$C:$C`), but that's usually dog slow in modern excel, or using `OFFSET` which never shrinks, but is volatile.